# Bootstrap date picker-disable and enable on condition

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this date picker.
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

My concern is that I want to enable date picker on some condition. 
For example : I have a select box of a country and if country is US,  I want to enable date picker otherwise disable it.  Disabling the date picker means user can not select date or No date picker should pop-up. 
I am selecting date picker by date picker calendar icon not with textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use jquery and that your country select box is with class "country", then something like this should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".country").change(function(e){
    var country = $(".country").val(); //get the value of the country select
    if (country != "US") { // you probably use some id and not the country name as value
       $(".datepicker").datepicker("remove"); // remove the datepicker
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @ankitmaini if this is working for you, you should probably choose this as an Answer?

Comment: I wanted to do that but I'm not sure how to do that